# Error trying to open NetCDF file with xarray from s3 bucket

Tags: python, netcdf, amazon-web-services, xarray

I'm trying to open a .nc file from an S3 bucket using xarray, but I'm getting an error. Here's the method I'm using:

```
import xarray as xr

aws_url = 's3://nasanex/NEX-GDDP/BCSD/rcp85/day/atmos/tasmax/r1i1p1/v1.0/tasmax_day_BCSD_rcp85_r1i1p1_inmcm4_2100.nc'
ds = xr.open_dataset(aws_url, engine='netcdf4')
```

the error being thrown is

> OSError: [Errno -128] NetCDF: Attempt to use feature that was not turned on when netCDF was built.: b's3://nasanex/NEX-GDDP/BCSD/rcp85/day/atmos/tasmax/r1i1p1/v1.0/tasmax_day_BCSD_rcp85_r1i1p1_inmcm4_2100.nc'

I have `netCDF 4.8.1` on my mac. Additionally the [xarray docs](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/user-guide/io.html#cloud-storage-buckets) say that data should be accessible through an s3 url of this type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the your `netcdf` engine cannot read this file as it is [invalid](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/user-guide/io.html#invalid-netcdf-files) for this engine.

To solve that you need to install [h5netcdf](https://github.com/h5netcdf/h5netcdf) engine using pip or conda.

Also, files from s3 cannot be directly read unless it is [zarr file](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/user-guide/io.html#cloud-storage-buckets). You should use [s3fs](https://pypi.org/project/s3fs/) library to open the file and read it with xarray with `h5netcdf` as your engine.

```py
!pip install s3fs h5netcdf --quiet

import s3fs 
import xarray as xr

fs = s3fs.S3FileSystem(anon=True)
aws_url = 's3://nasanex/NEX-GDDP/BCSD/rcp85/day/atmos/tasmax/r1i1p1/v1.0/tasmax_day_BCSD_rcp85_r1i1p1_inmcm4_2100.nc'

with fs.open(aws_url) as fileObj:
  ds = xr.open_dataset(fileObj, engine='h5netcdf')
```

Note: Restart the runtime after installing those packages.

Working [copy](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1kUB19Xpdubp3WUAECFgLNNp1WhWeoItz?usp=sharing)